# How can I get the URL of the currently connected MongoDB database from inside Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

**Background**: I am preparing a Meteor app for production, and in particular I am adding server logging. To do this I am using [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) with the [MongoDB plugin](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-mongodb). This requires the URL to the database. These databases are different between production and development environments so I want to set it programatically.

I am trying to avoid running forking a script to run

```
# meteor mongo --url
```

I also don't have access to $MONGO_URL on the development server (it doesn't appear to be set, for instance in process.env.MONGO_URL)

I expect that there is something like below, but I couldn't find this in the documentation or via Google.

```
Meteor.MongoDB.getURL();
```

Sorry if this is something really obvious...it feels like it should be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works server side. It needs Meteor 1.0.4+ (I think. Added somewhat recently):

```
var collection = new Mongo.Collection("some_collection");

console.log(collection.rawCollection().db.options.url)
```

Keep in mind you can have multiple MongoDB's (at least at the collection level, or this is how the design is at least, anyway) so you need to query a collection for its Mongo URL.

Comment: You should have realized it was a very sill question and treated it as such. Asking "What is the URL I connected by" when something in your configuration "must" have specified that in order for the connection to be made is a clear response. So why "introspect" something that should already be available from another source? Some questions just do not deserve answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

As mentioned in the question, the MONGO_URL environmental variable was undefined, but that appears to be either a misunderstanding or a bug in my IDE.

When I logged the value of process.env, I saw that MONGO_URL was indeed set, so I've used that.

In short:

```
process.env.MONGO_URL
```

Comment: If the question can't be properly answered in its current form (since we didn't have any data on your IDE or whatever), please delete it. It can't really benefit anyone in this current state...